# TypeError: setResult is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, axios

I tried to run this code but it is saying that TypeError: setResult is not a function

here is the code

```
const {result, setResult} = useState([]);

 useEffect(() => {
       axios(proxyurl + url)  
            .then(res => res.text)
            .then(res => setResult(res))
            .catch(err => console.log(err))
    }, [setResult]);    
    console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your doing wrong here,

```
const {result, setResult} = useState([]);
```

You probably want to do this,

```
const [result, setResult] = useState([]);
```

From, [react docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate), `useState` returns a array of two value,
Consisting, a stateful value, and a function to update it.